# Searching all pages of my website

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html file:

```
<ul id="intro" class="horizontal"> 
    <li> 
        <form>
            <input type="search" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
        </form> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Now I need a JS code to take the input that the user enters in the search textbox and goes through every single page (file) I created for the site and returns the pages containing exact/relevant words to the user. What is the shortest way to achieve that?

Comment: You'll probably need to do this from your code behind. Is that an option?

Comment: Read all the files
match the string 
return that file 
:)